# Revtex4-1 Question Mark Inside Brackets for Citations, No matter how I change it problem persists!

Tags: bibtex

Here is my LaTex Code:

```
\documenclass[aps,prl,reprint,groupedaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\author{Justin}

\affiliation{Department of Physics}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}\textbf{Hey}

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Cells /cite{Farlex09}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{bone}

\end{document}
```

My Bibtex File bone.bib

```
@article{Farlex09,
author={Farlex Partners},
url={http://medical-dictionary.com},
year=2009,
note={Online:accessed 20-February-2017}
}
```

I don't understand what the deal is but no matter what I do I get 
in my PDF.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste your code here as text rather than posting a screenshot. We can't edit screenshots to provide an answer. In this case, you seem to have forgotten the `\bibliographystyle{}` command. Also, I don't know whether BibTeX likes blank lines. But you'd get an error in that case, I assume, and not just question marks.

Comment: You also should make sure you have run `bibtex` (sequence: `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`).

Comment: I have read that alot through my research, but a friend of mine wrote a program to compile my PDF from Emacs using a single key stroke and I am not sure how to manipulate that program in order to accommodate the specific sequence.

Comment: You need a backslash before `cite` - not a forward slash. You can compile from outside emacs if necessary to test what's happening. Just run `pdflatex <filename>,tex; bibtex <filename>; pdflatex <filename>.tex; pdflatex <filename>.tex` or `latex` instead of `pdflatex`, if you're using `latex` instead. The advantage of this is that it is easier to see the errors and warnings when you run the programmes this way. (I don't know how `emacs` handles this, but many editors don't run the programmes interactively in case of an error.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I found that my coded compiler will not work with Bibtex, but I can use it to preview while I am writing my document. Then at the end I will compile it via pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex to add my sources.